# function of functions fails although manual calling always works in R

Tags: r, function, nested, lapply

I have a strange issue that is a bit hard to replicate, but I will explain the gist of it and hopefully there are suggestions to where I should look for potential errors.

First, I have a data frame, df, which I subset in to N data frames and apply a function on it, this function is defined as:

```
f <- function( anydataframe ) {
    f1 <- function(df) 
    f2 <- function(f1, df)
    ...
    f10 <- function(df, f1 , f9)
    return(f10)
```

In other words my function depends on other functions, and returns a data frame.

Now, my initiail data frame is large, and so too is N, so I want to be able to do something like

```
x <-  list()
for(i in 1 : 10000){
x[[i]] <- subset(df, condition i)
}
```

then be able to do:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(x, f) )
```

for some reason this fails, to investigate, I tried to do it using a for loop:

```
y <- list()
for ( i in 1:10000) { y[[i]] <- f(x[[i]])
```

which returns some pretty weird errors, such as:

```
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignment
```

however, there are no NAs in my code. The very weird thing is that when I run the sub functions manually, like this:

```
y <- list()
    for ( i in 1:10000) {
         f1(x[[i]])
         f2(f1, x[[i]])
          ...
         f10(x[[i]],f1,f9)
}
```

it works, with out errors. So the problem is not really with the way I'm writing my sub-functions, rather R doesn't like it when I combine them into one overall function, `f`. This solution isn't adequate though as I am trying to use lapply to get it running faster..... help!

Comment: This sounds like a scoping problem. Try using `=` or `<<-` instead of `<-`. When you define inside a function, I believe it stays there (in that environment) as opposed to globally available. But I am not sure.

Comment: @BryanGoggin thanks! that actually works, is there a good reference for the difference between `<<` and `<`? i can only find any material on the difference between `=` and `<` -- i had previously tried `=` btw and that did not work

Comment: Yep, see: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html #5 I believe covers `<-` vs `<<-`